# C And Windows API: Using Tab Control And Detecting Tab Change

Tags: c, winapi

I am working on a small program in C and Windows API. I have made a tab control and two tabs in it.
My questions are:

- Is my code fine? I have added some static controls but they do not hide when I change tab. I tried making tab control their parent but no help. For now, the main window is their parent(also the parent for tab control)
- If my approach is fine, how can I hide the controls when tab is switched?
- I read somewhere that a good approach is to make a dialog window that is parent for all other controls and hide it when needed? If I need to use that, can you please tell me how or direct me to a tutorial?

Code:

```
// Tab Control Declaration
   hTab = CreateWindow(WC_TABCONTROL, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                    10, 10, 765, 545, hwndq, (HMENU) 1, h_hinst, NULL);
// Tab 1 : See Student Info
tie.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
tie.pszText = TEXT("Student Info");
count = SendMessage(hTab, TCM_GETITEMCOUNT, 0, 0);
SendMessage(hTab, TCM_INSERTITEM, count, (LPARAM) (LPTCITEM) &tie);
// Tab 2 : Make A Question File
tie.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
tie.pszText = TEXT("Question Maker");
count = SendMessage(hTab, TCM_GETITEMCOUNT, 0, 0);
SendMessage(hTab, TCM_INSERTITEM, count, (LPARAM) (LPTCITEM) &tie);

            // STATIC CONTROLS
            // These will not change at runtime
            CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), TEXT("Enter Student Id:"),
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_GROUP | SS_LEFT,
                110, 65, 200, 20,
                hwndq, (HMENU) 0, NULL, NULL);
            CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), TEXT("Student Name:"),
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,
                110, 135, 200, 20,
                hwndq, (HMENU) 0, NULL, NULL);
            CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), TEXT("Tests Taken:"),
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,
                110, 175, 200, 20,
                hwndq, (HMENU) 0, NULL, NULL);
            CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), TEXT("Question Answered:"),
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,
                110, 215, 200, 20,
                hwndq, (HMENU) 0, NULL, NULL);
            CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), TEXT("Correct Answers:"),
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,
                110, 255, 200, 20,
                hwndq, (HMENU) 0, NULL, NULL);
            CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), TEXT("Incorrect Answers:"),
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,
                110, 295, 200, 20,
                hwndq, (HMENU) 0, NULL, NULL);
            CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), TEXT("Score In Last Test:"),
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,
                110, 335, 200, 20,
                hwndq, (HMENU) 0, NULL, NULL);
            CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), TEXT("Overall Score:"),
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,
                110, 375, 200, 20,
                hwndq, (HMENU) 0, NULL, NULL);

            // DYNAMIC CONTROLS
            // They change at runtime to display/accept data
            st[0].name = "Demo";
            st[0].tests_taken = "0";
            st[0].q_ans = "0";
            st[0].q_cor = "0";
            st[0].q_inc = "0";
            st[0].r_score = "0";
            st[0].t_score = "0";
            CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), st[0].name,
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_GROUP | SS_LEFT,
                475, 135, 200, 20,
                hwndq, (HMENU) 0, NULL, NULL);
            CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), st[0].tests_taken,
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,
                475, 175, 200, 20,
                hwndq, (HMENU) 0, NULL, NULL);
            CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), st[0].q_ans,
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,
                475, 215, 200, 20,
                hwndq, (HMENU) 0, NULL, NULL);
            CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), st[0].q_cor,
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,
                475, 255, 200, 20,
                hwndq, (HMENU) 0, NULL, NULL);
            CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), st[0].q_inc,
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,
                475, 295, 200, 20,
                hwndq, (HMENU) 0, NULL, NULL);
            CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), st[0].r_score,
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,
                475, 335, 200, 20,
                hwndq, (HMENU) 0, NULL, NULL);
            CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), st[0].t_score,
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,
                475, 375, 200, 20,
                hwndq, (HMENU) 0, NULL, NULL); 
            break;
```

Comment: You have to capture the `WM_` event (I can't remember), and hide the controls accordingly. "Is my code fine" is too general of a question. Fine in what context?

Comment: Well, fine as in, "making all controls child of main window is fine or should I make statics children of tab"? And regarding WM_ event, which one? I am a beginner and don't know about it?

Comment: You might want to check out this handy app for Win32 GUI programming: [`Resource Editor`](http://www.resedit.net/). It is much easier to work with resource based code than writing all the GUI elements manually into code.

Comment: @Athabaska Thanks for comment. However, I found the TabCtrl_GetCurSel( hwnd ) macro on MSDN(it was burried under tons of info) and using it, I will show and hide the controls accordingly.